# Tooltip should appear after typing two letters of the hotstrings-

Tags: autohotkey

This is the working autohotkey script. it generates tootips from hotstrings. I want that tooltip should appear after typing two letters. Please modify the script as I am not able to do so.

```
Loop, Read, %A_ScriptFullPath%
If RegExMatch(A_LoopReadLine,"^\s*:.*?:(.*)", line) ; gathers the hotstrings
hs.= line1 "`n"

Loop {
Input, out,V L1, {BS}
If out in ,,,`t,`n, ,.,?,! ; hotstring delimiters
ToolTip % str:= ""
else
ToolTip % RegExReplace(hs,"m`a)^(?!\Q" (str.= out) "\E).*\n" )
}

~BackSpace:: StringTrimRight, str, str, 1

::xnc::eccentric
::xnt::excellent
::xps::expertise
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the length of the typed string - in this case the variable **str** - you can do that with the http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/StringLen.htm command - the changes have been made in the *ELSE* section of the script below.

```
Loop, Read, %A_ScriptFullPath%
If RegExMatch(A_LoopReadLine,"^\s*:.*?:(.*)", line) ; gathers the hotstrings
hs.= line1 "`n"

Loop {
    Input, out,V L1, {BS}
    If out in ,,,`t,`n, ,.,?,! ; hotstring delimiters
        ToolTip % str:=""
    else
        {
         str.=out
         if (StrLen(str) > 1) ; means 2 or more, so if you want the tooltip to appear after 4 characters it will be > 3
            ToolTip % RegExReplace(hs,"m`a)^(?!\Q" (str) "\E).*\n" )
        }
     }
```